# Probelms Intstalling Trac using apt-get Ubuntu Jaunty

Tags: ubuntu, installation, python, apt, trac

I'm having some issues getting apt to install trac correctly on my Ubuntu Jaunty Box.

Using the command 'apt-get install trac' I get the following output:

> ```
> root@myserver:~# apt-get install trac
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
>
> Since you only requested a single operation it is extremely likely that
> the package is simply not installable and a bug report against
> that package should be filed.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   trac: Depends: python-setuptools (> 0.5) but it is not installable
>         Depends: python-pysqlite2 (>= 2.3.2) but it is not going to be
> ```
>
> installed
>               Depends: python-subversion but it is not installable
>               Depends: libjs-jquery but it is not installable
>               Recommends: python-pygments (>= 0.6) but it is not
>   installable or
>                           enscript but it is not installable
>               Recommends: python-tz but it is not installable
>       E: Broken packages

I have successfully used the command on my karmic kola desktop machine and am able to create new projects etc.

I thought I might be able to solve the problem by installing all python related extensions. This produced a very similar output.

I have Main, universe and multi-verse repositories enabled. Its a remote machine and I have no access to the gui.

Hope someone can help, googleing failed to solve the issue or find a solution!

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

That sort of dependency breakage doesn't make sense. The versions that the error message is complaining about are available in Jaunty (e.g. [version 0.6c9 of python-setuptools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/python-setuptools)).

I would check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`, and make sure that the same mirror is getting main, universe, and multiverse for jaunty, jaunty-security, and jaunty-updates.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do the dangerous

> apt-get update ;
>   apt-get upgrade

to get all packages on the same version.

Tough maybe a install from source would be more safe: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall

Jeroen

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using easy_install.

See the documentation http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one version of python installed on this system?  I've seen similar problem reports where it turns out that the necessary modules are installed for one version of python, and the webserver is using a different version.  This can happen with 32bit vs 64bit, or 2.4 vs 2.5, etc.